# No model named metron

Tags: django, pinax

I am looking to use Pinax to help speedup the process of creating a website in Django.

I started out by following the guide as follows.

```
[***@vps-1087814-7905 sites]# virtualenv mysite-env
[***@vps-1087814-7905 sites]# source mysite-env/bin/activate 
(mysite-env)[root@vps-1087814-7905 sites]# django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/zipball/master Project_x
(mysite-env)[root@vps-1087814-7905 sites]# cd Project_x
(mysite-env)[root@vps-1087814-7905 Project_x]# pip install -r requirements.txt

(mysite-env)[***@vps-1087814-7905 Project_x]# pip install metron
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): metron in /****/mysite-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So. Where did I go wrong? Metron is clearly installed, but for some stupid reason it claims that it is not installed. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What version of Django are you using? There isn't a models.py for metron - https://github.com/eldarion/metron, it's just a template tag library.

Answer (score 0):

Include metron in your apps variable in your settings.py. :)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (...,"metron")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Metron in your virtual environment.
        pip install metron